# How to communicate two services in Android?

Tags: java, android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am building app to collect sensoric data received from bluetooth le. Additionally, I need to collect smartphone location from installed GPS sensor. To achive this, I made three services:

1. First to retrive sensoric data from bluetooth le
2. Second to get gps location
3. Third, is foreground service to collect data from above services and save collected data to file in external storage

For now, I am using broadcast receiver to send data between services, but I know this is bad solution. What is best practice to achive communication between services?

Comment: have each one write to the database (or to cloud based DB like firebase) and then read it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library:

```
//1. Define a java class that represents your event:
public static class MessageEvent {
    /* Additional fields if needed */ 
}

//2.Post events at your origin like as below and receive them in destination (@Subscribe methods):
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());

//3.Prepare subscribers in destinations: Declare and annotate your subscribing method, optionally specify a thread mode:
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
    /* Do something */
};

//4.Register and unregister your subscriber in the destination, according to your component (here service class) life cycle:
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I hope this helps you.